# density function estimation using neural network

Tags: python, r, neural-networks

I firstly generate data from a bivariate normal distribution with `mean (0,0)` and `var cov (2, 0.5; 0.5, 2)`.

Here is my code for it:

```
n <- 10000
set.seed(123) #for reproducible results
dat <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=n, 
               mu=c(0, 0), 
               Sigma= matrix(c(2, 0.5, 0.5, 2), byrow=T, ncol=2)
)
```

Now what I want to do is ignore that I know the data is normal.
I would like to approximate the density function using a neural network and compare the estimated model and the true one.
I try to search the literature and I found "Density estimation addresses one of the most fundamental problems in machine learning, the
problem of discovering structure from data in an unsupervised manner". in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.13233.pdf
I am wondering can the Neural Density Estimation be implemented on this problem?

Comment: To be fair this question may be more suited for another stack exchange, furthermore neural network are used to learn features and do classification. To make them work, you need annotated data for the learning phase. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The traditional way would be to use something like [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) to fit the data to any function (gaussian, exponential, ...), then analyze the residuals for goodness of fit. No machine learning involved.